# Auto change color on dark and light theme backgrounds

Tags: jquery, html, css

a light-dark theme. My theme up is light and down is dark colors (blur).

[My them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVr64.jpg)

Now I create some box on this them but I've problem on the top of this theme (lighter). I've to use black font, and down boxes need to be white font, but I can't create black and white boxes because boxes will move with screen resize and black boxes may come to black screen (down) and nothing show! Also I can't set background for this boxes (for any reasons). Do you have any sujestion for this problem? I heard one thing that scss can detect background color and with light and dark level of background, set color (but also i don't use background at all  and it is background image (color are from image not css). What should I do for this problem?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

</head>

<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }

    #Background {
        background-image: url("bc.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #Background .Box {
        width: 350px;
        height: 250px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 25px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-top: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #Background .Box span {
        font-size: 48px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div id="Background">
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>
    <div class="Box"><span>TEST 1</span></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[bc.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x94gA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal and browser support is not great but `mix-blend-mode` might be an option here.

[**Mix-blend-mode @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, pink, purple);
  height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<h1>MY TEXT</h1>
<h1>MY TEXT</h1>
<h1>MY TEXT</h1>
<h1>MY TEXT</h1>
<h1>MY TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: My background color is are image color  not css color. so i don't think Mix-blend detect background color. please check the source (post updated).

Comment: It clearly is using the background color but there is `background-blend-mode` for images.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard one thing that scss can detect background color and with light and dark level of background, set color

^ Never heard of this, would be a useful feature for sure.

One solution would be to add responsive classes to each section for example a div may look like

```
<div class="small-dark medium-dark large-light xlarge-light"></div>
```

Where you would have media queries for each class and example would be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .small-dark {
     // Dark Styling Here
  }
  .small-light {
     // Light Styling Here
  }
}
```

^ You would do this for each media query and you'd have to manually check through screen resolutions to know which classes to add to divs. Rather than repeating yourself for each style I would use `extends` in `SASS` here.

Comment: i didn't understant it. but it seam's this is the way to solve. can you fix the source please (with the source updated the post)?

Comment: Normally I'd help you sort this out but I think the good people of SO like to promote learning over tutorials writing and they're not wrong. Try looking for more examples on writing [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) and [here](https://www.freecodecamp.com/) is a good place to get a free and more comprehensive understanding. Not a bad use of time to learn how to do things right.